# How to add a scrolling area to a table in Wt (witty)

Tags: c++, wt

How can I put an automatic vertical scroll bar inside a table (WTable) I've made in the WtApp (The class that is given to WRun command) constructor? My problem is I can't figure out how to give the WScrollArea's constructor its proper parameters. Should I absolutely give it a WContainerWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all you really needed to do was to make an object of WScrollArea class and have a WScrollBar attached to it as its child and make your table parent of the WScrollArea. Simple as that :D